# Electron auto launch packaged application starts welcome window

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-packager

I am working on an electron test application for windows.

The goal is an auto launching application which displays a popup message everytime the windows user logs in.

**Scenario:**

1. I'm executing `npm start` to package my code. (index.js +
   package.json)
2. I execute the generated `.exe` which will popup my message. (so far so good, right?)
3. I sign out from windows (`CTRL + L ALT + DEL` if this is important) and sign in again to test the application.
4. The popup opens but the default electron welcome page, too.

*package.json*

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "description": "",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "main": "index.js",

    "scripts": {
        "test": "electron .",
        "start": "electron-packager . Test --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --overwrite"
    },

    "author": "",
    "license": "MIT",

    "build": {
        "appId": "com.test.test",
        "win": {
          "target": "NSIS"
        }
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "auto-launch": "^5.0.5"
    },

    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "latest",
        "electron-packager": "^12.1.1"
    }
}
```

*index.js*

```
const {app, dialog} = require("electron");
const AutoLaunch = require("auto-launch");

app.on("ready", function(){
  dialog.showMessageBox({ message: "We are ready to take off! :-)", buttons: ["OK"] });

  let autoLaunch = new AutoLaunch({
    name: "test"
    // path: app.getPath("exe")
  }).isEnabled().then((isEnabled) => {
    if (!isEnabled){
            autoLaunch.enable();
            dialog.showMessageBox({ message: "AutoLaunch enabled.", buttons: ["OK"] });
    }
    else dialog.showMessageBox({ message: "AutoLaunch already enabled.", buttons: ["OK"] });
  });

  app.quit();
});
```

**Edit:** Found a problem that prevents the `package.json` being updated. A simple `npm info` resulted in a completely unexpected output.

Comment: A quick look at that package (auto-launch) you need to define a path, which you have commented out.. all that package does is set an autostart in the various systems.. npm start wont work it needs to be built

Comment: npm-start launches the packager which results in a complete stnadalone built. https://www.npmjs.com/package/auto-launch says: options.path - String (optional for NW.js and Electron apps)

Comment: ok sorry missed your scripts.. (genrally start is not used, instead build is, test is also dev but hey..), but the rest stands..

Comment: It's optional if it's installed.. Check the source.. https://github.com/Teamwork/node-auto-launch/blob/master/src/AutoLaunchWindows.coffee

Comment: If I change "start" to "build" I get an error message in the cmd. I will check it right now. I have the feeling the path is necessary and must be absolute.

Comment: Check the to see if the [reg](https://github.com/Teamwork/node-auto-launch/blob/master/src/AutoLaunchWindows.coffee#L8) key is set and the correct value.

Comment: Checked and is correct. I also tried https://github.com/linkRachit/Electron-sample-app which leads to the same problem. Seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, totally forgot about this question.
The solution was following:

Update all dependencies.
Make sure, that the path to the .html / .js file is absolute and correct.

An absolute path start with a `/`
For example `/files/index.html`

That's how it works!